# Driver properties for db2jcc in Squirrell and MON_GET_CONNECTION table function

Tags: jdbc, db2, db2-9.7

I'm trying to set driver properties like:

- clientAccountingInformation
- clientApplicationInformation
- clientProgramId
- clientProgramName

in Squirrell 3.6 (http://squirrel-sql.sourceforge.net/). See https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.apdv.java.doc/src/tpc/imjcc_r0052607.html for a more detailed description of these properties.

I was under the impression that it should be possible to inspect these values with for example:

```
select APPLICATION_HANDLE, APPLICATION_NAME, APPLICATION_ID
     , CLIENT_WRKSTNNAME, CLIENT_ACCTNG, CLIENT_USERID
     , CLIENT_APPLNAME 
from table(MON_GET_CONNECTION(cast(NULL as bigint), -2))
```

but no matter what values I use, I get null back from the query.

The db cfg regarding metrics are:

```
Request metrics                       (MON_REQ_METRICS) = BASE
Activity metrics                      (MON_ACT_METRICS) = BASE
Object metrics                        (MON_OBJ_METRICS) = BASE
Unit of work events                      (MON_UOW_DATA) = BASE
Lock timeout events                   (MON_LOCKTIMEOUT) = HISTORY
Deadlock events                          (MON_DEADLOCK) = HISTORY
Lock wait events                         (MON_LOCKWAIT) = HISTORY
```

Thoughts anyone, what am I missing?

Comment: Are you sure your client does indeed set these properties? Did you try setting them with some other client program, e.g. Data Studio?

Comment: No, I'm not sure of that. It might be the case that Squirrel ignores them. My next step where to create a small standalone java app, but I'll try with Data Studio first. Thanx for the idea.

Comment: It appears to be working with Data Studio (the driver that is shipped with that). I'll try that driver together with Squirrel next week and see if db2jcc is what is causing this.

Comment: I removed my answer since it no longer works with the jcc4 driver in Squirrel (not sure if it ever did, could be connection from DataStudio). I'll try DataStudio with the jcc driver and see if I get that to work.

Comment: DataStudio works with both db2jcc and db2jcc4 so it appears as if there is something wrong with the way Squirrell handles additional properties for the driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears to be a bug in the way Squirrel handles additional parameters. Data Studio acts as expected with both db2jcc and db2jcc4 drivers. I have filed a bug to:

```
https://sourceforge.net/p/squirrel-sql/bugs/1201/
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, I checked the URL after nearly 5 years, but sadly the status is still: `Status: open    Owner: nobody`. So I would not put my hopes too high for this to be fixed.